# Alternative to DimTime or DimDate in AdventureWorksDW?

Tags: date, calendar

Are there any free download alternatives to the DimTime or DimDate tables found in the AdventureWorksDW database?
I only want this table. Additionally, it would be great going to like 50 or 100 years in the future..

Thanks,
Sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ETL software and generate that kind of table by yourself, e.g. in [Pentaho ETL](http://www.pentaho.com/explore/pentaho-data-integration/) should be example transformation which creates time dimension. Using that kind of software gives posibility to chooose output format. Using that kind of software gives posibility to choose output format.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you are satisfied with the responses you got, 
but you can also create your own DimDate table based on your business requirements. 
I wrote the following code, based on the AdventureWorksDW212 DimDate table structure.

```
    --change [YourDatabase] to your database's name
    USE [YourDatabase] 
    GO

    --First Create the Table (dbo.DimDate)
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.DimDate') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.DimDate;

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate](
        [DateKey] [int] NOT NULL,
        [FullDateAlternateKey] [date] NOT NULL,
        [DayNumberOfWeek] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [EnglishDayNameOfWeek] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [SpanishDayNameOfWeek] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [FrenchDayNameOfWeek] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [DayNumberOfMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [DayNumberOfYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [WeekNumberOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [EnglishMonthName] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [SpanishMonthName] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [FrenchMonthName] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [MonthNumberOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [CalendarQuarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [CalendarYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [CalendarSemester] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [FiscalQuarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [FiscalYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [FiscalSemester] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_DimDate_DateKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [DateKey] ASC
    )
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
        ON [PRIMARY],
        CONSTRAINT [AK_DimDate_FullDateAlternateKey] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [FullDateAlternateKey] ASC
    )
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
        ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

      GO
    --I have used the table structure to resemble the DimDate table 
    --in the AdventureWorksDW2012 DB but you can modify to meet your needs
    --After the table is created, use the following code to populate the table:

    --Create a DATE type variable (@StartDate) to hold the start date
    DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE; 

    --Create another DATE Type variable (@EndDate) to hold the end date
    DECLARE @EndDate AS DATE;

    --Initialize @StartDate
    SET @StartDate = '2015-01-01';

    --Initialize @EndDate
    SET @EndDate = '2020-12-31';

    WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
    BEGIN

    --When populating the DimDate table,
    --Use a set operation because it is much faster than the regular "INSERT INTO" operation!

    INSERT dbo.DimDate 

    SELECT
        CONVERT(char(8), @StartDate, 112) AS DateKey, 
        CONVERT(char(10), @StartDate, 126) AS FullDateAlternateKey, 
        DATEPART(DW, @StartDate) AS DayNumberOfWeek, 
        DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) AS EnglishDayNameOfWeek,

        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Saturday'  THEN 'Sábado'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'    THEN 'Domingo'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Monday'    THEN 'Lunes'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Tuesday'   THEN 'Martes'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN 'Miércoles'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Thursday'  THEN 'Jueves'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Friday'    THEN 'Viernes'
            END AS SpanishDayNameOfWeek,

        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Saturday'  THEN 'Samedi'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'    THEN 'Dimanche'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Monday'    THEN 'Lundi'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Tuesday'   THEN 'Mardi'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN 'Mercredi'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Thursday'  THEN 'Jeudi'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Friday'    THEN 'Vendredi'
            END AS FrenchDayNameOfWeek,

            DATEPART(DD, @StartDate) AS DayNumberOfMonth, 
            DATEPART(dayofyear, @StartDate) AS DayNumberOfYear,
            DATEPART(WK, @StartDate) AS WeekNumberOfYear,
            DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) AS EnglishMonthName,

        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'January'    THEN'Enero'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'February'   THEN 'Febrero'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'March'      THEN    'Marzo'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'April'      THEN 'Abril'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'May'        THEN 'Mayo'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'June'       THEN 'Junio'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'July'       THEN 'Julio'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'August'     THEN 'Agosto'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'September'  THEN 'Septiembre'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'October'    THEN 'Octubre'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'November'   THEN 'Noviembre'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'December'   THEN 'Diciembre'
            END AS SpanishMonthName,

        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'January'    THEN 'Janvier'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'February'   THEN 'Février'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'March'      THEN 'Mars'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'April'      THEN 'Avril'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'May'        THEN 'Mai'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'June'       THEN 'Juin'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'July'       THEN 'Juillet'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'August'     THEN 'Août'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'September'  THEN 'Septembre'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'October'    THEN 'Octobre'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'November'   THEN 'Novembre'
            WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) = 'December'   THEN 'Décembre'
            END AS FrenchMonthName,

            DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate) AS MonthNumberOfyear,
            DATEPART(Quarter, @StartDate) AS CalendarQuarter,
            YEAR(@StartDate) AS CalendarYear,

        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate) IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
            THEN 1
            WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate) IN (7,8,9,10,11,12)
            THEN 2
            END AS CalendarSemester,

        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GetDATE()) IN (7, 8, 9)    THEN 1
            WHEN DATEPART(MONtH, GetDATE()) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 2
            WHEN DATEPART(MONtH, GetDATE()) IN (1, 2, 3)    THEN 3
            WHEN DATEPART(MONtH, GetDATE()) IN (4, 5, 6)    THEN 4
            END AS FiscalQuarter,

        CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(@StartDate) < 7  THEN YEAR(@StartDate) --Assuming the fiscal year beings on the first of July 
            ELSE YEAR(@StartDate) + 1 --if the date is less than July, then the Fiscal Year is equal to the Calendar Year
            END AS FiscalYear,

        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate) IN (7,8,9,10,11,12)    THEN 1
            WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate) IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)       THEN 2
            END AS FiscalSemester

            --Increment the @StartDate by 1 here:
            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate);

    END

    --You can now test your code by selecting from the table:
    SELECT * FROM DimDate;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange what an excellent, polite and thorough answer. To fit with the style of the site you should probably separate your code from your message (i.e. the part you have included between the code comment characters `/* */`). Keep up the good work ;-) Cheers